# Can I create a Conda Environment using .py file instead of .yml?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, environment

```
conda env create -f python3.6-environment.yml
```

This is the code I used to try to create an environment on conda, using a .yml file.

```
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .
```

After running the first code, I get stuck at this.

However, I noticed that I can copy the contents in the .yml file & create a .py file with it.

```
conda env create -f python3.6-environment.py
```

Can I then run this code instead & have all the same files installed as with the .yml?

The contents of the .yml file are from github: 
https://github.com/enigmampc/catalyst/blob/master/etc/python3.6-environment.yml

Comment: What do you mean "create a .py file"? The operating system doesn't care what extension is after the period, if it has the same content. What is your objective here?

Answer (score 0):

I think conceptually this works but for the sake of factoring I would suggest you write the activation as a bash script that also instantiates your python code. Just a thought.